# Ansible failing to unarchive bz2 files

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I'm not being able to extract a `.bz2` file using the Ansible `unarchive` module although it is present:

```
 - name: unpack Android NDK
   unarchive: copy=no src="{{ ansible_cache_dir }}"/"{{ android_ndk_zipfile }}" dest=/opt/android creates=/opt/android/"{{ android_ndk_folder }}"
```

Getting this error message :

```
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null, 
            "backup": null, 
            "content": null, 
            "copy": false, 
            "creates": "/opt/android/\"crystax-ndk-10.2.1\"", 
            "delimiter": null, 
            "dest": "/opt/android", 
            "directory_mode": null, 
            "exclude": [], 
            "extra_opts": [], 
            "follow": false, 
            "force": null, 
            "group": null, 
            "keep_newer": false, 
            "list_files": false, 
            "mode": null, 
            "original_basename": "\"crystax-ndk-10.2.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2", 
            "owner": null, 
            "regexp": null, 
            "remote_src": false, 
            "selevel": null, 
            "serole": null, 
            "setype": null, 
            "seuser": null, 
            "src": "/opt/ansible_cache\"/\"crystax-ndk-10.2.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2", 
            "unsafe_writes": null, 
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "Source '/opt/ansible_cache\"/\"crystax-ndk-10.2.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2' does not exist"
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that Ansible can't find the original archive.  I think it's because of the double quote syntax in your params.  Try quoting the entire parameter rather than just the variables.

```
- name: unpack Android NDK
  unarchive:
    copy: no
    src: "{{ ansible_cache_dir }}/{{ android_ndk_zipfile }}" 
    dest: /opt/android
    creates: "/opt/android/{{ android_ndk_folder }}"
```

Comment: Tried double quoting the params as mentioned but still stuck with error

Comment: Does the archive exist on the remote server?  With `copy: no` Ansible will look on the remote server for the archive rather than the local system.

Comment: Yes affirmative, the archive has been downloaded and present on remote host.  This is the error after quoting the params: ' "msg": "Failed to find handler for \"/opt/ansible_cache/crystax-ndk-10.2.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2\". Make sure the required command to extract the file is installed. Command \"/bin/tar\" could not handle archive. Command \"/usr/bin/unzip\" could not handle archive."'

Comment: Well that's an improvement :). Ansible can find your archive now but it can't unpack it.  Some possible debugging steps going forward: 1. Make 
 sure GNU tar is installed on the remote server 2. redownloading the archive (it worked for me first time so your archive may have gotten bonked) 3. unarchive manually and repack it in some other format (zip, tar, tar.gz, tar.xz).

Comment: Getting "msg": "dest 'opt/android' must be an existing dir" from above code although it is there.  GNU tar installed, redownloading done.  Guess only thing is to unarchive manually which rather sucks..

Comment: Using tar on the remote machine to extract archive manually and it did not work either giving "unexpected EOF in archive..." errors!  Maybe the archive itself is corrupt!  Looking into this and updating ..

Comment: Checking the SHA256 revealed that the file was not downloading properly and this was failing the unarchive module!